# Como fazer o var_export exportar array na sintaxe curta

Tags: php

De acordo com o Manual do PHP, sobre a função `var_export`

> `var_export()` obtém informação estruturada sobre uma dada variável. Ela
>   é similar a `var_dump()` com uma exceção: a representação retornada é um
>   código PHP válido.

Ou seja, ela deve retornar um código PHP válido para um dado valor passado por parâmetro.

O problema é que, no PHP 5.4, as definições para um `array` mudaram. Você não precisa mais usar a palavra-chave `array`, e sim apenas utilizar o colchetes.

Exemplo:

```
// Versões anteriores ao PHP 5.4
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
// Versões iguais ou posteriores ao PHP 5.4
$a = [1, 2, 3]
```

Quando efetuo o `var_export` nesse mesmo array (mesmo no PHP 5.4), ele me retorna isso:

```
array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, )
```

Eu gostaria que o `var_export` retorna-se o array dessa forma:

```
[ 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, ]
```

Existe alguma maneira de resolver essa situação?

O PHP já corrigiu isso em versões mais recentes?

Comment: Porque não usas o `var_dump()` mesmo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `var_export` continua exportando as variáveis no formato `array()` nas [versões mais recentes](http://3v4l.org/1594H).

Apesar do PHP 5.4 introduzir a sintaxe simplificada de arrays com colchetes `[ ]`, a utilização de arrays no formato `array()` continua funcionando sem problemas.

Alterar a saída do `var_export` para sintaxe curta só traria mais problemas para quem utiliza versões antigas e é uma alteração supérflua, já que a sintaxe comum ainda funciona `array()`.

Talvez no futuro quando `array()` não existir mais isso seja alterado.

Comment: Acho que uma expressão regular para resolver isso seria a solução então! Porém, ficaria muito complexo!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters mas converter para que? Algum motivo específico? array() ainda funciona normalmente

Comment: é porque eu quero mesmo :) Eu queria poder exportar o código e tê-lo com os colchetes.